# replace an array object with an additional element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array with `id` and `des` elements. i want to add extra element like `value:0` in that `array`. So i have tried it with a loop and done it.

```
let data = [
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "des": "aaa"
    },
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "des": "aaa"
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let tempObj = {
        "id": data[i].id, "des": data[i].des, "value": 0
    }
    data[i] = tempObj;
}
```

Is it possible can do without loop? In javascript any JavaScript functions are available?

Comment: **without loop** ? can you elaborate more?

Comment: do you always need `value: 0` ? if you need index, you can do something like `data.map((x,index) => Object.assign({}, x, {value:index}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without a loop, but you can simplify the code using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method(or use [spread syntax in ES6](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/peacock-145609/database)).

```js
let data = [{
    "id": 1001,
    "des": "aaa"

  },  {
    "id": 1002,
    "des": "aaa"
  }
];

var res = data.map(o => Object.assign({
  value: 0
}, o));


console.log(res);

// or alternatively you can use spread syntax
var res1 = data.map(o => ({ ...o, value: 1 }));


console.log(res1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` (to loop through and transform each element of the array) and the spread operator (`...` - allows you to easily copy all properties of an object to a new object):

```
data.map(x => ({ ...x, value: 0 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` but it will anyway loop through all the elements internall though it wont look like one.

I am using `Object.assign()` to create the new object.

```js
let data = [{
    "id": 1001,
    "des": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id": 1002,
    "des": "aaa"
  }
];

let newData = data.map(el => Object.assign( el, {value: 0} ));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` over the array and use [`spread operator syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let data = [{
              "id": 1001,
              "des": "aaa"

            },

            {
                "id": 1002,
                "des": "aaa"

            }
        ];
    
data = data.map(obj => ({...obj, value: 0}))
console.log(data)
```